# Get result of merging a PR while it is already merged

Tags: git, github, merge, refs

For a PR with number 1 GitHub automatically creates a ref `refs/pulls/1/head` and `refs/pulls/1/merge`. The latter contains the result of the merge and is especially useful for e.g. CI (because what you want to test is actually the result of the merge).

After merging a PR, the `refs/pulls/<number>/merge` is no longer available (I suppose because the PR is no longer mergeable). Currently I want to run a test on a version that was merged a while ago. Is there an easy way to access the result of the merged PR, given just the PR number?

Comment: Perhaps I did not made myself clear. The problem is that I'm actually looking for the merge commit (e.g. its sha), given just the PR number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick even though you should be aware that there are possibly multiple "children" of a commit (someone else could base work on the PR and merge it into master again later):

```
$ git rev-list -n1 upstream/pull/<number>..upstream/master
```

This works by getting the first commit walking from `upstream/pull/<number>` to `upstream/master`. Luckily github leaves `upstream/pull/<number>` just on the last commit of the PR.

Here's an example of https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib:

It's current history looks like this:

```
* 371263f - (upstream/pull/486) Removed debugging print statement
...
*   fe3fa52 - (upstream/master, upstream/HEAD) Merge pull request #482
|\
| * 354c352 - (upstream/pull/482) fix broken example
|/
*   f81e0b2 - Merge pull request #480
....
```

Here some test output:

```
$ git rev-list -n1 upstream/pull/482..upstream/master
fe3fa522b48e787fa87dc1156e1a10bd6671b62c
$ git rev-list -n1 upstream/pull/486..upstream/master
(no output)
```

Comment: Wow, you must know a lot about git.. Thanks a lot!